# Is mBytesPerFrame needed in AudioStreamBasicDescription?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audio, core-audio, audioqueueservices

In `AudioStreamBasicDescription` struct:

```
struct AudioStreamBasicDescription {
    Float64 mSampleRate;
    UInt32  mFormatID;
    UInt32  mFormatFlags;
    UInt32  mBytesPerPacket;
    UInt32  mFramesPerPacket;
    UInt32  mBytesPerFrame;
    UInt32  mChannelsPerFrame;
    UInt32  mBitsPerChannel;
    UInt32  mReserved; 
};
```

if we know nChannelsPerFrame and mBitsPerChannels, we can calculate mBytesPerFrame like this:
`mBytesPerFrame = mBitsPerChannels * mChannelsPerFrame / 8` (correct me if I'm wrong)

I believe that all of the fields exist for some reason. What is it for mBytesPerFrame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The field can be used to aid in describing packing and alignment of LPCM sample data/frames. That's also mandatory for describing some external LPCM representations.

For example, you can specify a 20 bit sample size, but an implementation may favor to represent/transfer/store that using 3 bytes, or 24 bits (ignoring 4 bits per sample).

Comment: the similar question, why do we need mBytesPerPacket if we already have mFramesPerPacket and mBytesPerFrame?

Comment: @jAckOdE you're welcome. there's overlap and seemingly redundant fields because the ASBD can represent LPCM and basic VBR formats. `mBytesPerPacket` is especially useful for defining an abstract description of basic VBR data without ambiguity.